# Given a 2D integer grid, how to choose three points (x,y), (2x,2y) and (3x,3y) such that their distance to the integer grid is maximal?

Tags: geometry

Given an integer grid $\mathbb{Z}^2=\{...,(0,0), (1,0), (2,0),...,(1,1),(1,2),...\}$, choose $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the points $(x,y)$, $(2x,2y)$, $(3x, 3y)$ have maximal (Euclidean) distance from any point of the integer grid $\mathbb{Z}^2$ (i.e. the closest point to the grid is as far as possible from the grid).

How to solve this problem mathematically? Or else, which iterative algorithm would be best suited to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is supposed to be a comment but it is a little bit long and I need to post a picture to illustrate some points.

For any $k \in \mathbb{R}$ and $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Let $d_{k,mn} : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be the distance between $(kx,ky)$ and $(m,n)$

$$d_{k,mn}(x,y) = \sqrt{(kx - m)^2 + (ky - n)^2}$$

Let $d_k(x,y) = \min\limits_{m,n \in \mathbb{Z}} d_k(x,y)$. The question at hand is equivalent to:

> What is the biggest value of 
>   $d(x,y) = \min\{\; d_1(x,y), d_2(x,y), d_3(x,y) \;\}$ for $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$?

It is easy to see $d_k(x,y)$ is a doubly periodic function with fundamental period $(\frac1k,0)$ and $(0,\frac1k)$. Furthermore, for any $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$,

$$d_k(x,y) = d_{k,mn}(x,y) \quad\text{ for }\; (x,y) \in [\frac{m-1/2}{k},\frac{m+1/2}{k}] \times [\frac{n-1/2}{k},\frac{n+1/2}{k}]$$

and $d_k(x,y)^2$ is equal to a quadratic polynomial in $x$ and $y$.

This means $d(x,y)^2$ is a piecewise smooth doubly periodic function with fundamental period $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. It is also clear $d(x,y)$ is an even function in $x$ and in $y$ and remain unchange if we swap the role of $x$ and $y$. To locate the biggest value of $d(x,y)$, one can
restrict the search to points inside the triangle $\triangle ABC = \{\; (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 0 \le y \le x \le \frac12 \}$ shown in the figure at end.

Using the periodicity of $d_k(x,y)$, we know over $\triangle ABC$,

$$\begin{align}
d_2(x,y) &= \min\{\; d_{2,00}(x,y), d_{2,10}(x,y), d_{2,11}(x,y) \;\}\\
d_3(x,y) &= \min\{\; d_{3,00}(x,y), d_{3,10}(x,y), d_{3,11}(x,y) \;\}
\end{align}$$
Since $d_{1,00}(x,y) \le d_{2,00}(x,y) \le d_{3,00}(x,y)$, we find over $\triangle ABC$,
$d(x,y)$ is the minimum of the square root of 5 quadratic polynomials. 
$$d(x,y) = \min\{\; d_{1,00}(x,y), d_{2,10}(x,y), d_{2,11}(x,y), d_{3,10}(x,y), d_{3,11}(x,y) \;\}$$

Let $R = \frac{\sqrt{23-3\sqrt{31}}}{5}$. The point $(x_0,y_0) = \left(\frac{4+\sqrt{31}}{20}, \frac14 \right)$ mentioned in the comment of another answer is the intersection of 3 circles

$$d_{2,10}(x,y)^2 = d_{2,11}(x,y)^2 = d_{3,11}(x,y)^2 = R^2$$

If one make a plot for the five circular regions when some $d_{k,mn}(x,y) < R$:
$$\begin{array}{lrcrcrl}
(\color{red}{red})       & d^2_{1,00}(x,y) &=& x^2      &+& y^2      &< R^2\\
(\color{orange}{orange}) & d^2_{2,10}(x,y) &=& (2x-1)^2 &+& (2y)^2   &< R^2\\
(\color{yellow}{yellow}) & d^2_{2,11}(x,y) &=& (2x-1)^2 &+& (2y-1)^2 &< R^2\\
(\color{green}{green})   & d^2_{3,10}(x,y) &=& (3x-1)^2 &+& (3y)^2   &< R^2\\
(\color{blue}{blue})     & d^2_{3,11}(x,y) &=& (3x-1)^2 &+& (3y-1)^2 &< R^2
\end{array}$$

One will obtain the figure at end. The interior of these 5 circles cover the triangle $\triangle ABC$ nearly completely and the only exception is the point $(x_0,y_0)$. This implies for all $(x,y) \in \triangle ABC$ and hence $\in \mathbb{R}^2$, we have $$d(x,y) \le d(x_0,y_0) = \frac{\sqrt{23-3\sqrt{31}}}{5}$$

$\hspace1.5in$ [image: circular regions for the 5 distances]

**Update**

The conclusion that $d(x,y)$ reaches maximum on $(x_0,y_0)$, the common intersection of
three contour lines from three different distances $d_{k,mn}$ isn't a coincidence.
It is a consequence of following lemma:

> Let $f(x,y), g(x,y)$ be two smooth functions defined over a neighborhood $\mathcal{O}$
>   of a point $p \in \mathbb{R}^2$ satisfying following conditions:
>
> - $\mathcal{C} = \{\; (x, y) \in \mathcal{O} : f(x,y) = g(x,y)\;\}$ is a regular curve passing through $p$.
> - $\vec{\nabla} f(p) \ne \vec{\nabla} g(p)$.
> - the [Hessians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) of $f$ and $g$ are positive definite over $\mathcal{O}$.
>
> then $p$ cannot be a local maximum of $h(x,y) = \min\{\; f(x,y), g(x,y)\;\}$.

To see why this is the case. Assume the contrary and let us parametrize $\mathcal{C}$ by its arc length near a local maximum $p$ of $h(x,y)$.

$$\gamma : ( -\epsilon, \epsilon ) \ni s \quad\mapsto\quad \gamma(s) = (x(s),y(s)) \in \mathcal{C}\quad\text{ with }\quad \gamma(0) = p$$

Let $\vec{t} = \gamma'(0)$ be the tangent vector at $p$ and $\mathcal{H}f$, $\mathcal{H}g$ be the Hessian matrices
$$
\mathcal{H}f = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2} &
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y} &
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}
\end{bmatrix}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\mathcal{H}g =
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial x^2} &
\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial x\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial x\partial y} &
\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial y^2}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Since $p$ is a local maximum of $h(x,y)$, at $s = 0$, we will have

$$\begin{cases}
(f\circ\gamma)'_p
&= \vec{\nabla} f_p \cdot \vec{t} = 0\\
(g\circ\gamma)'_p
&= \vec{\nabla} g_p \cdot \vec{t} = 0\\
\end{cases}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\begin{cases}
(f\circ\gamma)''_p
&=  \vec{t}\cdot \left[ \mathcal{H}f_p \vec{t} \right] + \vec{\nabla} f_p \cdot \gamma''(0) \le 0\\
(g\circ\gamma)''_p
&=  \vec{t}\cdot\left[ \mathcal{H}g_p \vec{t} \right] + \vec{\nabla} g_p \cdot \gamma''(0) \le 0
\end{cases}$$
Since we parametrize $C$ by arc length, $|\vec{t}| = 1$. Togather with the assumption
$\mathcal{H}f$ and $\mathcal{H}g$ are positive definite, we obtain
$$
\begin{cases}
\vec{t}\cdot \left[ \mathcal{H}f_p \vec{t} \right] > 0\\
\vec{t}\cdot \left[ \mathcal{H}g_p \vec{t} \right] > 0\\
\end{cases}
\quad\implies\quad
\begin{cases}
\vec{\nabla} f_p \cdot \gamma''(0) < 0\\
\vec{\nabla} g_p \cdot \gamma''(0) < 0\\
\end{cases}
$$
This implies all three vectors $\vec{\nabla} f_p$, $\vec{\nabla} g_p$, $\gamma''(0)$
are non-zero and both $\vec{\nabla} f_p$, $\vec{\nabla} g_p$ are pointing in the same direction as $-\gamma''(0)$. A consequence of this if we crosses $C$ along the direction
$-\gamma''(0)$ at $p$, $h(x,y)$ will increases as we move away from $\mathcal{C}$. This contradicts with the assumption that $p$ is a local maximum of $h(x,y)$ $\blacksquare$.

Back to our original problem, the maximization of 
$$d(x,y) = \min\{\; d_{1,00}(x,y), d_{2,10}(x,y), d_{2,11}(x,y), d_{3,10}(x,y), d_{3,11}(x,y) \;\}$$
over $\triangle ABC$ is equivalent to the maximization of
$$d^2(x,y) = \min\{\; d^2_{1,00}(x,y), d^2_{2,10}(x,y), d^2_{2,11}(x,y), d^2_{3,10}(x,y), d^2_{3,11}(x,y) \;\}$$

over the same triangle.

Since all the $d^2_{k,mn}(x,y)$ involved are smooth functions with positive definite Hessians. $d^2(x,y)$ cannot achieve a local maximum at $(x,y)$ where only one of the $d^2_{k,mn}$ is larger than all the rest.

Since the set $\mathcal{C}$ corresponds to any two such $d^2_{k,mn}$ are either circles or straight lines. They are regular curves. What this means is the local maximum of $h(x,y)$ can only achieved at those point where either:

- at least three of $d_{k,mn}$ coincides.
- or only two of $d_{k,mn}$ coincides but the gradient at that point also matches.

i.e. To find the maximum of $d(x,y)$, there are only finitely many $(x,y)$ to check.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation!

Comment: I understand this problem better now, and I'll mark your reply as accepted answer (I believe you showed the proposed solution is correct and unique up to symmetries).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

First, we can assume that both $0<x\leq 0.5$ and $0<y \leq 1$ with a little transformation

If $(0,0)$ is the closest point of the grid to $(2x, 2y)$, $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$ or $(1,1)$ is the closest point of the grid to $(3x, 3y)$

If $(1,0)$ is the closest point of the grid to $(2x, 2y)$, $(1,0)$ or $(1,1)$ is the closest point of the grid to $(3x, 3y)$

If $(0,1)$ is the closest point of the grid to $(2x, 2y)$, $(0,1)$ or $(1,1)$ is the closest point of the grid to $(3x, 3y)$

If $(1,1)$ is the closest point of the grid to $(2x, 2y)$, $(1,1)$ is the closest point of the grid to $(3x, 3y)$

Solve the 11 equations (7 with symetries) and you'll get your answer

Comment: Actually, can't we also assume $0<y<x$, given the reflection symmetry ?

Comment: By assuming $0<x<1/2$, $0<y<x$ and that $(2x,2y)$ and $(3x,3y)$ are closest to $(1,1)$, I found the solution $(x,y)=(1/5+\sqrt{31}/20;1/4)$. I'm not sure how to prove that this solution is the only one for $0<x<1/2$ and $0<y<x$, however.

Comment: @derren with a $\leq$ yes, i used it to go from 11 to 7 equations.